# Complex analysis, find the residue

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

> Find the residue of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2\sin z}$ at $z_0=0$

What I tried

Let $g(z)=1$ and $h(z)=z^2\sin z$, both are analytics but they have zeros of different orders then $f(z)$ don't have removable singularity point at $z_0$

Then I tried to use the fact that if $lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}(z-z_0)^kf(z)$ exists, then $f(z)$ have pole of order $k$ at $z_0$, but I'm stuck on this, because if for example I take $k=2$
$$lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}(z-0)^2\frac{1}{z^2\sin z}=lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{1}{\sin z}=\infty$$

Maybe I need to do some transformation in the function, but I can not see such a transformation.

Comment: So why not take $k=3$.

Comment: @quid $lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{z}{\sin z}=\frac{0}{\infty}$, this is indeterminacy is not it? Or can I do this?

Comment: It is rather $0/0$ and if you use l'Hospital or something you'll see that the limit is in fact $1$ so the pole is of order $3$.

Comment: @quid Ok I will try, I did not know he could apply L'Hospital

Comment: Actually I used L'Hospital more as a buzzword to give the right idea. Likely it is better you use the series expansion in that context if you want to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may write, as $z \to 0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{z^2\sin z}&=\frac1{z^2\left(z-\dfrac1{3!}z^3+O(z^5)\right)}\\\\
&=\frac1{z^3\left(1-\dfrac16z^2+O(z^4)\right)}\\\\
&=\frac1{z^3}(1+\frac16z^2+O(z^4))\\\\
&=\frac1{z^3}+\frac1{6z}+O(z)\\\\
\end{align}
$$ and the desired residue is equal to $\dfrac16$.

Comment: what is $O$ in your answer?

Comment: @askazy $f(z)=O(z^4)$ just means that $\left|f(z)/z^4\right| \leq C$ as $z \to0$, for some constant $C$. Thanks.

Comment: How did you find the reciprocal of a series?

Comment: @OlivierOloa I tried to do through series of laurent, but I can not get the same answer.

Comment: @grdgfgr You may use $\frac1{1-u} = 1+u+O(u^2)$ as $u \to 0$.

Comment: What if we needed the next term in the sequence?

Comment: @grdgfgr Please, see my edited comment.

Comment: @askazy May I see your steps, thanks.

Comment: @OlivierOloa I managed to get the answer through limit, but as I write the Laurent series for $\frac{1}{\sin z}$?

Answer (score 0):

You can always expand the function into a Laurent series using $\frac{1}{z^2}\cdot$ the Taylor series of csc(z) then the residue will be the coefficient of the term indexed  by -1.